# Update Multiple Keychain entries

Tags: keychain

Is there a way to run an automator script to update multiple keychain entries at once?  I have a client that is part of an AD and when they update their pw it doesn't update the keychain.  I am looking for a way to update multiple entries at once.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

#### The CLI for keychains is security.

It lets you do many things such as setting passwords:

```
security add-generic-password [-a account] [-s service] [-w password] [options...] [-A|-T appPath] [keychain]
```

Read the [man page](http://cl.ly/T8xk) for more info or do `security help`.